# What happened to Retsu's doll at the clothing shop?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the *Hunter X Hunter: Phantom Rouge* movie, what happened to Retsu's doll when she activates it after Gon and Killua step out to talk? We never see anyone exit the shop after Gon and Killua. Did she swap places with her doll?

She mentions she "left her doll in the shop for safekeeping;" what exactly happened here? How did she catch up to Gon and Killua in the alley?

[image: Dat doll]

Answer (score 3):

I finally got around to watching this and here is my theory on what exactly happened to the doll. After [***Retsu***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Retz) gets her dress [***Killua***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Killua) asks her to give [***Gon***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Gon) and him the location that she believes to be where the [***Pairo***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Pairo) doll is that contains [***Kurapika***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Kurapika)'s eyes. After a small argument Killua asks Gon for a moment alone so they walk outside to the alley. Before the even leave the store Retsu uses the Soul 
Doll ability. According to the HxH wikia a brief description states:

> The ability to make a doll copy of a person that the target is strongly thinking about. Conditions in performing Soul Doll are :
>   Omokage's doll must be adjacent to the target while that person is thinking of someone. When the doll is adjacent to the target, it will turn into the person that the target is thinking about. The real person of whom the doll is based cannot feel or notice this (without actually being there). ref([***Omokage Abilities***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Omokage))

During the brief exchange with Gon, Killua has the ever present flashback of [***Illumi***](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Illumi) telling him that he will betray his freinds. After Retz comes out and addresses them in the alley they leave, the scene zooms back into the alley and we see a purplish aura that grows into a humanoid shadow.

So my theory is since Retsu can manipulate her doll without strings she sent it after Gon and Killua in the alley and once the Soul Doll ability was activated it caught on to Killua's thinking of Illumi and once they left the alley it transformed into the Illumi doll that we see later on in the movie.